# How to store from external javascript variable value to html variable value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to store the jquery variable value to the html variable value.

Here is my code,

This is the javascript function which is in external javascript page

```
function createImage(settings) {
    var kk = createCanvas(settings)[0].toDataURL('image/png');
    }
```

Now, this is in html page

```
var karan = kk;
<img id="containerQrCode" src = "+ karan +" alt="qr image" />
```

Now, how can I move the kk value which is in external javascript page to the karan variable which is in html page.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will suggest you work with the DOM. Some thing like the below if your are jQuery.

```
function createImage(settings) {
    var kk = createCanvas(settings)[0].toDataURL('image/png');
    $("#containerQrCode").attr("src", kk);
}
```

below can be tried if not using jquery

```
function createImage(settings) {
    var kk = createCanvas(settings)[0].toDataURL('image/png');
    document.getElementById("containerQrCode").setAttribute("src", kk);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
<img id="containerQrCode" src = "
    <script type="text/javascript>document.write(karan)</script>
" alt="qr image" />
```

Sorry misread about setting the variable as well, try this:

Edit the function to say this:

```
function createImage(settings) {
    var kk = createCanvas(settings)[0].toDataURL('image/png');
    return kk;
}
```

Then update where you set karan to this:

```
var karan = createImage();
```

You will also need to include the external javascript file in the project like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/your/file.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var karan = kk;
var img = document.getElementById('containerQrCode');
img.src = karan;
```